# jquery select iframe with youtube embed src

Tags: jquery, select, youtube

If i want to select **all** youtube  iframes via their src how can this be achieved, i have tried the jquery below but it won't work?
the embed src is `http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid?rel=0`

```
<script>
$('iframe[src="http://youtube.com/embed/"]')
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write `src^="..."` to find `<iframe>`s with `src` that [*starts with*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `...`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write your script in jquery environment then you can use the attribute form in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var srcVAlue = $('iframe').attr('src');        
});
```

Comment: This question was asked a very long time ago, moreover this answer is wrong.