# How To Parse HTML to Find youtube or Vimeo Videos on page with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

How can I select a YouTube or Vimeo video from the page using Jquery, javascript or php?

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: send as a mock page so that we can decide

Comment: @Raj Did you get the solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [selector discussed in this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8205584/437226).  Using `src^="..."` will let you select the iframe whose source attribute starts with something.

For YouTube, you would use:

```
$('iframe[src^="http://youtube.com/embed/"]')
```

For Vimeo:

```
$('iframe[src^="http://player.vimeo.com/video"]')
```

Comment: what about those pages that don't use iframes?

Comment: I think you may need to clarify your question.  I was assuming you were trying to select embedded videos.